# List assigning to another variable, then original variable also changes when there will happen an operation on child variable

Tags: python, list, insert, append

```
a = [1,2,4]
b=a
b.insert(1,45)
print(a,b)
```

results
a = [1,45,2,4]
b = [1,45,2,4]

why a is changing
is there any way, where b will change

Comment: `b=a` This does NOT make a copy.  `b` and `a` refer to _the same_ list object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're just reassigning the same instance. You need to do this instead of `b=a`:

```
b = a.copy()
```